# How to insert HTML entities with createTextNode?

Tags: javascript

If I want to add an ascii symbol form js to a node somewhere?
Tried as a `TextNode`, but it didn't parse it as a code:

```
var dropdownTriggerText = document.createTextNode('blabla &and;');
```

Comment: `&nbsp;` and `&amp;` and so forth are not ASCII codes, they are HTML entities.

Comment: Did you mean `&amp;`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't create nodes with HTML entities. Your alternatives would be to use unicode values

```
var dropdownTriggerText = document.createTextNode('blabla \u0026');
```

or set `innerHTML` of the element. You can of course directly input `&`...

Comment: If there already is a DIV element and you want to insert text including HTML entities, a document.createHtmlNode() function would be nice. E.g.: myHtmlNode = document.createHtmlNode('ABC&nbsp;DEF'); myParentNode.appendChild(myHtmlNode); But I guess using unicode values as suggested is still the nearest possible option to that.

Answer (score 10):

`createTextNode` is supposed to take *any* text input and insert it into the DOM exactly like it is. This makes it impossible to insert for example HTML elements, and HTML *entities*. It’s actually a feature, so you don’t need to escape these first. Instead you just operate on the DOM to insert text nodes.

So, you can actually just use the `&` symbol directly:

```
var dropdownTriggerText = document.createTextNode('blabla &');
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find an automated way to do this. So I made a function.

```
// render HTML as text for inserting into text nodes
function renderHTML(txt) {
  var tmpDiv = document.createElement("div"); tmpDiv.innerHTML = txt;
  return tmpDiv.innerText || tmpDiv.textContent || txt;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution given the circumstances. An option within `Document.createTextNode()` would be of course better, but your solution works.