# How can I add a html unicode onto createTextNode

Tags: javascript, html

So I've got a span

`<span class="delete-btn">&#x2718;</span>`

and am trying to include the HTML unicode for x - `&#x2718;` within a textNode -

`span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("&#x2718;"));`

however this simply isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert HTML entities with createTextNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941956/how-to-insert-html-entities-with-createtextnode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `\u2718` :

```js
let span = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-btn')[0];
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u2718'));
```

```html
<span class="delete-btn">&#x2718;</span>
```

Comment: Cheers, this works. How exactly does it work though?

Comment: @codfish555 You simply put the code for your character after a `\u`, it should print fine.

Comment: but doing the .textContent hides the unicode: document.createTextNode('a\u200eb').textContent  - how come?

Comment: @NadavB You have a typo in your text, there's a `a`. It should start with `\u`