# &nbsp not displaying properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, textnode

I'm trying to add lines to my page using javascript. I'm eventually planning on generating ascii art from it, but that's besides the point. For some reason, the text `|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|` renders properly as part of html, but not as a `textNode`. My MRE is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Test">
        |&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|
    </div>
    <script>
        testDiv = document.getElementById('Test')
        testDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
        testDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|'))
    </script>
</body>
```

On Chromium, it shows up as:

```
|    |
|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|
```

I've tried about 10 different ways to encode the non-breaking space, but I get a similar result no matter what. I've tried using `\` and `$#` for every encoding I can find. I have not tried it on a different browser.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+html+entity+not+rendered+createTextNode) of [How to insert HTML entities with createTextNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20941956/4642212). Inserting text (`.textContent`, `.createTextNode`) won’t parse HTML (including HTML entities), as opposed to inserting HTML (`.innerHTML`, `.insertAdjacentHTML`).

Comment: To parse HTML entities securely, try `testDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(new DOMParser().parseFromString('|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|', "text/html").documentElement.textContent));`. This will parse the HTML in an independent document which cannot execute any scripts.

Comment: @SebastianSimon can you elaborate on your security comment? Assuming that the string being appended is trusted, I don't see why this is necessary.

Comment: @importhuh The string possibly not being trusted is exactly the reason. `element.innerHTML = "&nbsp;"` works fine, but `element.innerHTML = '<img src="." onerror="alert(1);">'` can be dangerous. Such XSS attacks won’t happen with the `DOMParser` approach. The code, as written, also ignores HTML elements and only takes the resulting text content of HTML entities. See my answer to [Find and replace specific text characters across a document with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41886794/4642212) for more context.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your text in `<pre></pre>` tags. It would be rendered as you typed it. You won't need `&nbsp;`

```
<pre>
|    |
</pre>
```

```
|    |
```

**Javascript Example**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("PRE");
  var t = document.createTextNode("|     |");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicode literal for this case.

```js
document.createTextNode("|\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0|")
```